# str.format() problem

Tags: python

So I made this class that outputs '{0}' when x=0 or '{1}' for every other value of x.

```
class offset(str):  
    def __init__(self,x):  
        self.x=x  
    def__repr__(self):
        return repr(str({int(bool(self.x))}))
    def end(self,end_of_loop):
    #ignore this def it works fine
        if self.x==end_of_loop:
            return '{2}'
        else:
            return self
```

I want to do this:
`offset(1).format('first', 'next')`
but it will only return the number I give for x as a string.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your subclass of `str` does not override `format`, so when you call `format` on one of its instances it just uses the one inherited from `str` which uses `self`'s "intrinsic value as `str`", i.e., the string form of whatever you passed to `offset()`.

To change that intrinsic value you might override `__new__`, e.g.:

```
class offset(str):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __new__(cls, x):
        return str.__new__(cls, '{' + str(int(bool(x))) + '}')

for i in (0, 1):
  x = offset(i)
  print x
  print repr(x)
  print x.format('first', 'next')
```

emits

```
{0}
'{0}'
first
{1}
'{1}'
next
```

Note there's no need to also override `__repr__` if, by overriding `__new__`, you're already ensuring that the instance's intrinsic value as `str` is the format you desire.